# How to pass a props value to a JS function from Vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a JS file with a function and component as below:

```
function emojify(name){
  var emj='';
  if (name!=''){
    emj= '<img src="/static/emojis/'+name+'.png" alt="img" > '
  }
  return emj
}


Vue.component("cmp2",{ props:["name"] , template: `<p>` + emojify("name") + `</p>`})
```

I call that component from HTML as below

```
<cmp2 name="ron" ></cmp2>
```

Image of ron doesnt show up. But if i declare my component as below it works:

```
Vue.component("cmp2",{ template:'<p>' + emojify("ron") + '</p>'})
```

So the image ron exists and works fine. I am just unable to pass value of props `name` to the function `emojify`.
How can that be done?

Comment: [ERASE ALL PICTURES OF RON.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3Umrqg2GPQ)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this as the `template` is computed at compilation time but `props` are evaluated at run / render time.

What you can do is bind the `src` attribute, eg

```
<p>
  <img v-if="name" :src="`/static/emojis/${name}.png`" alt="img">
</p>
```